# How to get Microsoft365 Group members to SharePoint Online without 365Connector

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, office-365-groups

I'm using SharePoint Online modern experience.

I want to get Microsoft365 Group members to custom list.

I know if I use Office365 Group connecter(Power Automate) I can achieve that.
But I want to know the way that without that connecter.

Do you have any idea?

I would be very happy for any idea/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the default (free) Microsoft/Office 365 group connector then you can use the Microsoft 365 Group APIs (using Microsoft Graph) in Power Automate (premium connectors required).

You can get the member of M365 group members using API like:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members
```

You can learn more about how to work with M365 Group APIs at: [Fetch Office 365 Groups Programmatically Using Microsoft Graph API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fetch-office-365-groups-programmatically/)

And how to work with Microsoft graph in Power Automate at: [Calling Graph API From Power Automate Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-graph-api-from-power-automate-flow/).

I am not sure about all your requirements, But if you can achieve what you want using free M365 group connector then I will suggest to use that only because using premium connector will add more cost to your solution.